# Plone - Cannot untick "Inherit permissions from higher levels"

Tags: security, permissions, plone

On the sharing tab of any Folder or File, I can untick "Inherit permissions from higher levels", but when I click save, it does not stick.
I do not want my SalesGroup to have access to or even see the name of my ManagementFolder.

Plone 4.3.1 running on Windows. I have tried logging into Plone as admin & a folder owner. I have also tried from multiple browsers.

Comment: IT could be an errore, but you don't see any feedback for a combination of server side action and AJAX request.

Look for errors in the instance log. If you don't see anything try do disable JavaScript in that page and repeat the operation.

Comment: There's no question here. This is a bug report and should be filed in Plone's issue tracker.

Comment: It's probably already recorded, smells like http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Bug-on-sharing-page-upgrade-plone-app-workflow-to-2-1-6-td7566655.html

Comment: Since plone.app.workflow 2.1.6 may fix, I have downloaded it, but not sure how to install - could someone direct me to instructions?
Also, how would I disable JavaScript in that page?

Comment: Put `plone.app.workflow==2.1.6' in the eggs-section of your buildout-config, rerun buildout. For the latter you might want to open a new quest. HTH, i

Comment: @user2744908: Here is a quick instruction on how to install an add-on, which is the same procedure as for pinning in your case: http://euve4703.vserver.de:8080/adi/howto/plone-1/plone-quickest-start#install-add-on   The official doc propagated on plone.org/documentation is currently not published...

Comment: ... which I just wanted to report in Plone's tracker, but cannot log-in, getting a 500. Where to report that? ;)

Comment: @user2744908: Rereading your quest I realize you're on Windows, which my quick-steps don't consider. Could you autocratically find docs and proceed? Your feedback is very welcome to help improving the docs :)

Comment: FTR: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13734

Comment: Assumingly because of lacking feedback duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805351/cant-disable-permissions-of-parent-folder-in-plone