# Can't disable permissions of parent folder in Plone

Tags: permissions, plone, zope

In the Sharing-Setup of my folders and contents, I can't remove the permissions of the parent folder. When I untick the box and press save, it seems to load something but when I reload the sharing page, the box is ticked again.

Comment: You mean the 'acquire permissions' checkbox?

Comment: Can you please include what version of Plone and Zope you are using? Any way we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I mean the acquire permissions checkbox and I use Plone with the following version information:

Plone 4.3.1 (4306)
CMF 2.2.7
Zope 2.13.20
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) [GCC 4.6.3]
PIL 1.7.8 (Pillow)

I fear it won't be possible to reproduce the error from outside my network.

Comment: That form is partially done with AJAX, so you've probably a server side error. Unluckily in case of error the form is not giving you any feedback. Check your instance log.

Comment: In the error log I see get the following line for every time I tried to untick this option:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604039/plone-cannot-untick-inherit-permissions-from-higher-levels, didn't flag though, because no answer was provided there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating to Plone version 4.3.2.

There was an error in file plone/app/workflow/browser/sharing.py as described on this [GitHub page](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.workflow/commit/237c755b597ada0ead74696a32e4bee7e84ce03c).

Thanks for your help guys!